# Android Content Provider IllegalArgumentException Unknown URL Content

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider, illegalargumentexception

I'm new to Android content provider. I'm building a simple android application using content provider. Each time I insert data into the database, I got the error **IllegalArgumentException Unknown URL Content**.

My logcat errors

```
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763): Process: com.example.videouploadclient, PID: 32763
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL Content://com.example.videouploadclient.model.provider/video_table
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1203)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at com.example.videouploadclient.view.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:59)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-16 14:50:53.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32763):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
```

My code to insert data into the database

```
Uri uri;
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(VideoEntry.COLUMN_ID, 111);
contentValues.put(VideoEntry.COLUMN_TITLE, "my title");
contentValues.put(VideoEntry.COLUMN_DURATION, 9876);
contentValues.put(VideoEntry.COLUMN_DATA_URL, "");
contentValues.put(VideoEntry.COLUMN_CONTENT_TYPE, "video/mp4");
contentValues.put(VideoEntry.COLUMN_STAR_RATING, 4);
uri = getContentResolver().insert(VideoEntry.VIDEO_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
```

My contract class

```
public class VideoContract {
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.videouploadclient.model.provider";
    private static final Uri BASE_URI = Uri.parse("Content://" + AUTHORITY);


    public static final class VideoEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static String VIDEO_TABLE_NAME = "video_table";
        public static final Uri VIDEO_CONTENT_URI = BASE_URI.buildUpon()
                .appendPath(VIDEO_TABLE_NAME)
                .build();

//      table columns
        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_DURATION = "duration";
        public static final String COLUMN_CONTENT_TYPE = "content_type";
        public static final String COLUMN_DATA_URL = "data_url";
        public static final String COLUMN_STAR_RATING = "star_rating";

        public static Uri buildRowAccessUri (long id) {
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(VIDEO_CONTENT_URI, id);
        }
    }
}
```

My database helper class

```
public class VideoDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "video_upload_client_database";

    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_VIDEO =
            "CREATE TABLE " + VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + VideoEntry.COLUMN_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + VideoEntry.COLUMN_TITLE
            + " TEXT, "
            + VideoEntry.COLUMN_DURATION
            + " INT, "
            + VideoEntry.COLUMN_CONTENT_TYPE
            + " TEXT, "
            + VideoEntry.COLUMN_DATA_URL
            + " TEXT, "
            + VideoEntry.COLUMN_STAR_RATING
            + " INT)";

    public VideoDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,
              context.getCacheDir()
              + File.separator
              + DATABASE_NAME,
              null,
              DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_VIDEO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
                + VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

My content provider class

```
public class VideoProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public static final int VIDEO_ITEMS = 100;
    public static final int VIDEO_ITEM = 101;

    public static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();


    public static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

        matcher.addURI(VideoContract.AUTHORITY, VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME, VIDEO_ITEMS);
        matcher.addURI(VideoContract.AUTHORITY, VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME, VIDEO_ITEM);

        return matcher;
    }

    private static final String VIDEO_TABLE_NAME = VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME;
    private VideoDatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mDatabaseHelper = new VideoDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    private static String addKeyIdCheckToWhereStatement (String whereStatement, long id) {
        String newWhereStatement;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(whereStatement))
            newWhereStatement = "";
        else
            newWhereStatement = whereStatement + " AND ";

        return newWhereStatement + " _id = "
                + "'" + id + "'";
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String whereStatement,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        final SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case VIDEO_ITEMS:
            queryBuilder.setTables(VIDEO_TABLE_NAME);
            break;
        case VIDEO_ITEM:
            queryBuilder.setTables(VIDEO_TABLE_NAME);
            whereStatement = addKeyIdCheckToWhereStatement(whereStatement, ContentUris.parseId(uri));
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }

        final Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                projection, whereStatement, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

        String table;
        Uri returnUri;

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case VIDEO_ITEMS:
            table = VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME;
            returnUri = VideoEntry.VIDEO_CONTENT_URI;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " 
                    + uri);
        }

        final long insertRow = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(table, null, values);

        if (insertRow > 0) {
            Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(returnUri, insertRow);
            // Register to watch a content URI for changes.
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri,
                                                           null);

            return newUri;
        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Fail to add a new record into " 
                    + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        int rowsDeleted;
        final SQLiteDatabase database = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case VIDEO_ITEMS:
            rowsDeleted = database.delete(VIDEO_TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case VIDEO_ITEM:
            rowsDeleted = database.delete(VIDEO_TABLE_NAME, 
                    addKeyIdCheckToWhereStatement(selection, ContentUris.parseId(uri)), selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " 
                    + uri);
        }

        // Register to watch a content URI for changes.
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, 
                                                       null);

        return rowsDeleted;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {

        int rowsUpdated;
        final SQLiteDatabase database = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case VIDEO_ITEMS:
            rowsUpdated = database.update(VIDEO_TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case VIDEO_ITEM:
            rowsUpdated = database.update(VIDEO_TABLE_NAME, values, addKeyIdCheckToWhereStatement(selection, ContentUris.parseId(uri)), selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " 
                    + uri);
        }

        // Register to watch a content URI for changes.
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,
                                                       null);

        return rowsUpdated;
    }

}
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code. I've searched through many related topic without any answer.

Comment: Is all the code necessary for this particular bug ? Clean up the code and reduce his length for a better and quicker help.

Comment: I think it'd be better to show all the related code when I don't know where I'm get wrong

Comment: It was a question :-) I don't know the answer nor the problem. But I always give the advice to think about what piece of code is really usefull when a post have lots of code.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in `buildUriMatcher()`. The two URIs you add both have the same path, `VideoContract.VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME`.  I think the second replaces the first, so the code returned on a match of that path is `VIDEO_ITEM`.  In your `insert()` method, there is no case for `VIDEO_ITEM` so it does the default processing, which is to throw the `IllegalArgumentException` reported in your stack trace.

```
public static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    matcher.addURI(VideoContract.AUTHORITY, VideoContract.VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME, VIDEO_ITEMS);
    matcher.addURI(VideoContract.AUTHORITY, VideoContract.VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME, VIDEO_ITEM);

    return matcher;
}
```

Comment: You could use:
matcher.addURI(VideoContract.AUTHORITY, VideoContract.VideoEntry.VIDEO_TABLE_NAME + "/#", VIDEO_ITEM_WITH_ID);